# Prioritizing elements from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have to make a StarCraft-like game in a really simplistic way with pyton.

One of the task I have to do is to create a little farming algorithm in order to make the ships compute the distance separating them from the asteroid, choose the closest one sand go mine on it.

All of the game data is contained in a dictionary, here's a sample :

```
database = {
    'player1': {
        'type': 'player',
        'ships': {
            'shipOne': {
                'life': 3,
                'type': 'excavator-M',
                'taille': 5,
                'tonnage': 4,
                'remaining_tonnage': 4,
                'status': 'unlock',
                'portée': 0,
                'position': [20, 3],
                'attack': 0,
                'cost': 2
            },
            'shipTwo': {
                'life': 3,
                'type': 'excavator-M',
                'taille': 5,
                'tonnage': 4,
                'remaining_tonnage': 4,
                'status': 'unlock',
                'portée': 0,
                'position': [20, 3],
                'attack': 0,
                'cost': 2
            }
        },
        'actions': {
            'purchases': {},
            'moves': {},
            'mining': {},
            'attacks': {},
            '(un)lock': {}},
            'ores': 995},
            'parameters': {
                'turn_count': 19,
                'columns': 41,
                'lines': 40},
                'asteroids': {
                    '10 14': {
                        'capacity': 12,
                        'pos': [10, 14],
                        'farm_rate': 1
                    },
                    '5 21': {
                        'capacity': 12,
                        'pos': [5, 21],
                        'farm_rate': 2
                    },
                    '20 6': {
                        'capacity': 12,
                        'pos': [20, 6],
                        'farm_rate': 2
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried to proceed like this :

1° Create a copy of the dictionary['asteroids], that way I'll be able to virtually decrease the amount of ores contained in an asteroid and not send to much ships on the same asteroid.

2° Use a loop to create a dictionary 'ships_dest' in which I add each ships name as a key, the future element to associate to this key is the destination of the closest non-empty asteroid.

3° For each ship, I compute the distance separating it from all of the asteroids. And add this value in the dictionary samp_asteroids associated with the key 'distance'.

4° I create a list named 'priority_list' containing each asteroid name, it will be used to compare the distances in pairs and delete the farthest asteroid.

The the idea is to choose the closest asteroid with the highest farm rate and associate it with the correct ship in the dictionary ships_dest.

Here's what I tried :

```
ships_dest = dict()
samp_asteroids = copy.deepcopy(database['asteroids'])

priority_list = list()

for ship in database['player1']['ships']:
    ships_dest.update({ship:''})

    for asteroid in samp_asteroids:
        priority_list.append(asteroid)
        distance = abs(database['player1']['ships'][ship]['position'][0] - database['asteroids'][asteroid]['pos'][0]) + abs(database['player1']['ships'][ship]['position'][1] - database['asteroids'][asteroid]['pos'][1])
        samp_asteroids[asteroid].update({'distance':distance})

for ship in database['player1']['ships']:  

    for asteroid in samp_asteroids:

            if database['asteroids'][asteroid]['capacity'] != 0:

                if samp_asteroids[asteroid]['capacity'] != 0:

                    ships_dest.update({ship:database['asteroids'][best_ast(samp_asteroids,priority_list)]['pos']})

                    samp_asteroids[best_ast(samp_asteroids,priority_list)]['capacity'] -= database['player1']['ships'][ship]['tonnage']
```

Here's the function I use to choose the closest asteroid with the best farming rate :

```
def best_ast(samp_asteroids,priority_list): 
    """
    Browse a list containing each asteroids name and return the closest asteroid to the considered ship.

    Parameters
    ----------

    - samp_asteroids : dictionary containing the data about the asteroids on the board. (dict)

    - priority_list : list containing the name of each asteroid. (list)

    Return
    ------

    - The name of the closest asteroid with the best farming rate. (str)

    """

    if len(priority_list) == 1:
        return priority_list[0]

    else:
        if samp_asteroids[priority_list[0]]['distance'] > samp_asteroids[priority_list[1]]['distance']: # on garde la plus petite distance
            priority_list.remove(priority_list[0])

        elif samp_asteroids[priority_list[0]]['distance'] < samp_asteroids[priority_list[1]]['distance']: # on garde la plus petite distance
            priority_list.remove(priority_list[1])

        else:
            if samp_asteroids[priority_list[0]]['farm_rate'] < samp_asteroids[priority_list[1]]['farm_rate']:
                priority_list.remove(priority_list[0])

            elif samp_asteroids[priority_list[1]]['farm_rate'] < samp_asteroids[priority_list[0]]['farm_rate']:
                priority_list.remove(priority_list[1])

        return(best_ast(samp_asteroids,priority_list))
```

Does anyone has an idea to compare the distances separating ship and asteroid without using a list ? Or simply a smarter way of doing so because I end up with a RecursionError :

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-0fa8dfeb9b6e> in <module>()
     19                 if samp_asteroids[asteroid]['capacity'] != 0:
     20 
---> 21                     ships_dest.update({ship:database['asteroids'][best_ast(samp_asteroids,priority_list)]['pos']})
     22 
     23                     samp_asteroids[best_ast(samp_asteroids,priority_list)]['capacity'] -= database['player1']['ships'][ship]['tonnage']

<ipython-input-10-9786ab7c168e> in best_ast(samp_asteroids, asts)
     20                 asts.remove(asts[1])
     21 
---> 22         return(best_ast(samp_asteroids,asts))

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-10-9786ab7c168e> in best_ast(samp_asteroids, asts)
     20                 asts.remove(asts[1])
     21 
---> 22         return(best_ast(samp_asteroids,asts))

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Thank you !

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a [Minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems it's possible to go through `best_ast` without removing anything. Then it will call itself with the same arguments and will never stop doing so, until the stack runs out.

Comment: How many asteroids are there?

Comment: You really need to create a [mcve] with a minimal example of the data you are operating on.  Sometimes just doing this (reducing the code to a minimum that reproduces the symptom) illuminates the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) `priority_list` items on `distance` (*increasing*) and `farm_rate` (*decreasing*) then choose the best one.

Assuming `priority_list` items are similar to this, and the values are numeric:

```
p_list = [{'distance': 65, 'farm_rate': 0.9006277325425915},
          {'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.12482252401403537},
          {'distance': 63, 'farm_rate': 0.6915596366818075},
          {'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.50761770347844},
          {'distance': 43, 'farm_rate': 0.8675896228329137},
          {'distance': 43, 'farm_rate': 0.22372360159878157},
          {'distance': 67, 'farm_rate': 0.6110535887580553},
          {'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.2520264185913459},
          {'distance': 99, 'farm_rate': 0.31742690900315873},
          {'distance': 76, 'farm_rate': 0.3747398299123208}]
```

Write a function that returns the distance and (negative) farm rate.

```
from operator import itemgetter
both = itemgetter('distance', 'farm_rate')
def f(d):
    d, r = both(d)
    return (d,-r)
```

Use the function as the sort key:

```
p_list.sort(key=f)

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(p_list)
[{'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.50761770347844},
 {'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.2520264185913459},
 {'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.12482252401403537},
 {'distance': 43, 'farm_rate': 0.8675896228329137},
 {'distance': 43, 'farm_rate': 0.22372360159878157},
 {'distance': 63, 'farm_rate': 0.6915596366818075},
 {'distance': 65, 'farm_rate': 0.9006277325425915},
 {'distance': 67, 'farm_rate': 0.6110535887580553},
 {'distance': 76, 'farm_rate': 0.3747398299123208},
 {'distance': 99, 'farm_rate': 0.31742690900315873}]
```

The asteroid with the smallest distance and the highest farm rate should be the first one.

```
>>> p_list[0]
{'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.50761770347844}
>>>
```

Or just use the key function with `min()`:

```
>>> min(p_list, key=f)
{'distance': 8, 'farm_rate': 0.50761770347844}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can almost always re-implement a recursive as a non-recursive function:

```
def best_ast(samp_asteroids,priority_list):
    best = samp_asteroids[priority_list[0]]
    for p in priority_list:
        if best['distance'] > samp_asteroids[p]['distance']:
            best = p
        elif best['distance'] == samp_asteroids[p]['distance']:
            if best['farm_rate'] < samp_asteroids[p]['farm_rate']:
                best = p
    return best
```